# How do I open an apple keynote file in windows?

Tags: windows, mac, presentations, iwork-keynote

I only have the .key presentation file and cannot ask the author to export it to ppt nor do I have an Apple computer available.

Comment: Do you have access to an IWork account? (I deleted my answer as I misread your question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is now a [keynote viewer for the browser](http://flabbergasted-sjoerd.blogspot.com/2011/01/keynote-viewer-for-windows.html) using icloud. If you have a Apple device, you can make an icloud account, and upload the file to your account. then go to [icloud's website](https://www.icloud.com/) and play it on any browser.

Comment: I think this is the best answer now. A free account at https://www.icloud.com/ also lets you download as PDF or PowerPoint format

Comment: Apple device isn´t required now. I created my iCloud account from Windows in 2 minutes and started playing and editing the keynote.

Answer (score 14):

The following websites can convert the .key to PDF online:

- https://cloudconvert.com/key-to-pdf (tested on 2019-02-01)
- http://www.zamzar.com (tested on 2013-08-15)

Also, the .key is a zip archive: if you unzip you may be able to see a thumbnail for each slide.

Comment: Worked for me and I don't even have a mac!

Comment: I prefer this solution by far since it doesn't require creating an account.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a proprietary format, you will need to use KeyNote to open it.

You obviously can't export the file as anything since you would need to open it first in order to export it ;-)

I know that Keynote files can be "played" in QuickTime on a Mac, but I don't know how feasible that is in Windows. Worth a try.

Comment: To play keynote files in Quicktime on windows you would first need to export them to a .mov file apparently

Answer (score 1):

Creating an apple account is free and Key note is also free to use with that on ICloud. So we just needed to go to https://www.icloud.com create a user, log in with that and we have the abilities online on the browser

Comment: Which is fine as long as you never want to do any work offline...